# Reliability of Composite Variable Made of 4 Measures?

Tags: reliability

I am conducting some analyses with a composite variable constructed by averaging 4 separate measures. I would like to know the reliability of the composite variable. Is Cronbach's alpha appropriate in this case (even though I have entire scale scores instead of item scores), or is a different measure more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, you can use Cronbach's alpha for this. Bear in mind that it makes some assumptions, and is an _estimate_ of the reliability.